# Насколько релевантно переходить на Linux

Tags: linux, windows, пк

На данный момент у меня windows 10. Пока основной идеей для перехода является то, что Linux меньше весит. У меня суммарно 150гб памяти на ПК, пока нет возможности как либо улучшить эту ситуацию. Я fronted разработчик, почти fullstack. Учусь в среднем it вузе где учат все по немного. Какие ещё плюсы я могу получить от Linux? И как быстро я могу научиться работать с этой системой? Все что я знаю, что это какая-то операционная система, что там приходится работать с консолью. Есть ли там проблемы с установкой всяких программ по типу: node js, mySQL, git и прочих для написания кода? В windows это делается буквально за пару кликов, есть ли разница?

Comment: даже студент "среднего it вуза" (ОСОБЕННО студент it вуза) просто обязан уметь информацию такого рода самостоятельно.

Comment: На Linux можно установить все перечисленное одной командой. На Windows нужно зайти на сайт инструмента, скачать установщик, запустить. Это не пара кликов. Базово научиться пользоваться терминалом Linux можно ~за месяц.

Comment: Стоило бы начать с того, что Linux - это не операционная система. Это целая пачка разнородных программных наборов от разных вендоров. И какой-нибудь gentoo отличается от альт не меньше, чем они оба от windows. Установка программ обычно бинарная: если повезет, то в пакетном менеджере дистрибутива может быть нужная программа и ее можно будет поставить в пару кликов, а если нет - то программы под linux может вообще не быть.

Comment: Думаю, что танцы с бубном начнутся при написании всяких курсовых работ и дипломного проекта))) Когда Надо будет делать все по ГОСТ. Типичная ситуация: у  тебя все ок на компе, но потом несешь флешку чтобы распечатать в какое-нибудь агентсво.... и ... там все руинится =) Можно, конечно, через танец с бубном решить эти проблемы. Не скажу что это плохо, но просто много времени будет тратиться на все это "шаманство". Но, зато будешь прокачивать скилл =)

Comment: @АлексейБелкин чтобы не руинилось когда-то придумали формат PDF. Экспорт в PDF не занимает много времени.

Comment: @insolor, я в курсе. Но это и есть танец с бубном. Например, принес PDF, а при распечатке увидел, что фамилию забыл поменять))) А в агентстве, например не открывается .odt, или еще что-нибудь... Вообщем, веселуха будет)) Я помню как мои однокурсники постоянно с бубном плясали и по тысячу раз перепечатывали, особенно, когда они неправильно документы набирали или еще что-нибудь)))

Comment: Если агенство не открывает ODT, то такое агенство не соответствует ГОСТ Р ИСО/МЭК 26300-2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что в вопросе уже есть пара категоричных комментариев, я напишу ответ.

Конечно, все, кто уже написал о том, что Вы можете найти всю информацию сами по-своему правы.

Но пройдем немного дальше. Я сам в основном бэкэнд разработчик, но мне приходится иногда подпиливать фронтэнд. И у меня есть опыт работы на всех трёх операционках: винда, мак и Линукс с разными "мордочками"

Мои замечания я оформлю в виде списка, потому что наверняка понадобится уточнять что-то "по пунктам".

1. консоль нужна и в Винде. Консоль вообще сильно нужна разработчику. Она даёт доступ к мультиплатформенным инструментам, таким, которые используются для создания, модификации, настройки и публикации проектов. Причем, эти инструменты работают в линуксе и в Винде одинаково

Встроенная консоль никуда не годится, замена ей - либо мой любимый [cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder), либо [вин-терм](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701?hl=ru-ru&gl=RU), удивительно хорошо на этот раз получилось у Майкрософта

2. Десятую Винду нельзя назвать полноценной без двух инструментов: [докера](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/) и [WSL2](https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2020/07/13/zapusk-linux-v-windows-wsl-2/). А эти штуки так сильно стирают границы между виндой и линуксом, что разница становится уже совсем небольшой
3. чтобы ещё сократить эту разницу - можно освоить любой из пакетных менеджеров под Винду. Их не так много, как под Линукс, мне кажется, что проще всего разобраться с [официальным](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/package-manager/winget/), а полезнее всего с "[шоколадкой](https://chocolatey.org/)"
4. насчёт места. Винда и некоторое кол-во не очень больших проектов вполне живут на диске объемом 120 гигов. Им тесно, но жить можно. Линукс требует меньше места для "базовых вещей", и даёт ещё одно преимущество: файловые системы со встроенной дедупликацией. Фронтэндщики, у которых в каждом проекте 100500 зависимостей, особенно это оценят.
   Кстати, для винды, благодаря опенсоурсу, теперь тоже есть... Барабанная дробь... [ZFS for windows](https://habr.com/ru/post/374317/), и все её плюшки!

Так что- лично я не считаю, что современный Линукс на десктопе имеет преимущества перед современной виндой.

В Винде мне нравятся: шрифты, сочетания клавиш (потому, что для меня контрол+с и контрол+v ,принципиально лучше того же с шифтом), устойчивость системы к установке обновлений, большое кол-во драйверов, RDP - госсподи, как же он прекрасен по сравнению со всеми VNC, FreeNX и прочей ерундой, которая *должна* решить проблему удаленного доступа к графическому десктопу в линуксе, но нифига её не решает...

Самое смешное, что адепты линукса назвали бы для него примерно то же самое в качестве преимуществ!

Comment: Не знаю, что такое устойчивость системы к установке обновлений. У меня на Linux Mint обновления системы тихонько накатываются в фоне, потом уже сам перезагружаешься когда будешь готов. В целом особой "неустойчивости" за 3 года не заметил. На Windows при обновлении системы комп тупо на полдня становится недоступен. Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V с Shift нужно использовать только в терминале, а в стандартном терминале Windows они вообще не работают для копирования-вставки (копирование на самом деле работает через выделение + Enter, что не особо очевидно).

Comment: Момент по докеру на винде: нещадно жрёт свободное место на жёстком. На рабочей машине отказался от него.

Answer (score 3):

Для СРЕДНЕГО ВУЗа рекомендую использовать [подсистему линукс для виндовс](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/about)(компактнее чем виртуалка). Ведь для фулстек разработки понадобится иногда сносить всё и ставить ещё раз, а переустанавливать систему когда на ней диплом и важные документы не очень хорошая идея.

Comment: вот это я понимаю - короткий и грамотный ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Как человек, который недавно окончил ВУЗ, скажу, что переход на Linux - гиблое дело для студента. Всегда потребуется какое - нибудь ПО, которое становится на Linux либо с длительными танцами, либо не ставится совсем(либо ставится но не работает). Если вы хотите изучать Linux, то накатывайте две ОС. В вашем же случае, если не хватает памяти, то на мой взгляд лучше поставить более старую Windows(например семерку).

P.S. А вобще у вас неправильный подход, ищите решение, как увеличить мощности, а не урезать функционал.

Comment: Для студента - да, невозможность простой установки какого-нибудь MS Office может стать проблемой (альтернативные офисы могут показывать документы не так, как MS Office).

Comment: @insolor тут автору бы определиться студент он или разработчик)

Comment: Ну, в принципе одно другому не мешает, можно зарабатывать разработкой ПО и одновременно учиться в вузе

Comment: и студент и разработчик, разве это редкое явление?

Comment: @ПавелСоляник студент и разработчик который спрашивает релевантно ли переходить на ли линукс на мой взгляд достаточно редкое явление

Answer (score 1):

меньше весит такой себе критерий, дистры отличаются в основном пакетниками и системой обновления, если смотреть топ скачиваний на [дистроватче](https://distrowatch.com/), то там в основном дистры на базе арча и деб, еще пара на базе ред хата, я за арчеподобные, потому что синтаксис пакмана отличный, роллинг система обновления тоже, не нужно ждать очередных релизов дистра+любой софт есть в репах, можно подключить chaotic repo и ставить готовые пакеты aur без сборки, сам пользуюсь arcolinux plasma, имхо тут больше времени надо на выбор [DE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0) потратить, в которой будет комфортно работать, я когда то mate после gnome 2 юзал, сейчас хорошо доработали plasma, но все таки в планах освоить что то тайлинговое типа i3 или bspwm в связке с vim, чтобы меньше зависеть от мышки, был положительный годичный опыт пользования openbox, работа системы на хоткеях очень сильно ускоряет использование инструментов+нетребовательно к железу.
по железу нужно смотреть видео интел или амд, нвидеа недавно открыла вроде код драйверов, но все равно не ясно когда нормально допилят софт.

по поводу программирования, для фронта линухи удобны, потому что из коробки как минимум уже везде есть питон, все остальное можно доставить одной командой, для фронта считаю вполне приличный вариант, но если нужны пакеты адоба или программировать на шарпе, то лучше винда, потому что visual studio нет, только платный [rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/rider/)

И как быстро я могу научиться работать с этой системой?
можно взять за основу для понимания [как работает система](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)), там ответы есть на многие проблемы, которые возникнут, можно использовать на любом дистре с поправкой на команды пакетного менеджера, суть дистров внутри примерно одинакова
[второй вариант мат часть](https://www.youtube.com/c/KirillSemaev/playlists)

Есть ли там проблемы с установкой всяких программ по типу: node js, mySQL, git и прочих для написания кода
скорее всего nodejs git уже будут или подтянутся в процессе как зависимости софта, потому что на ноде много чего сейчас делается, а git итак понятно, куда без него, БД придется доставить, прочих для написания кода-vscode несколько версий, если что-то типа джетбрейнсов то тоже без проблем через флэтпак например, остальное надо просто гуглить, но любой опенсорсный пакетдолжен без проблем ставиться, с проприетарным софтом надо разбираться.

> 150гб
> это ssd или оперативка? а то времена такие пошли... ssd сейчас недорогие, можно за пару тысяч прикупить для комфортной работы, иначе делить этот объем 50/50 на root и домашнюю папку пользователя, если еще и винду оставлять второй системой, то места в процессе работы вообще в обрез будет, кэш пакетов после обновлений, бэкапы на всякий случай, место быстро кончится.

Comment: 150гб оперативки? это конечно круто. Но не могу представить ситуаци где столько оперативки может не хватить

Comment: >  из коробки как минимум уже везде есть питон, - видимо, мы по разному смотрим на то, что такое "и коробки"... есть дистрибутивы типа "сервер без нифига", там питона нет. Есть "развесистые" десктопные дистрибутивы, где можно поставить галочку "устанавливать питон", и он поставится. И, вы не поверите, это мало отличается от установки питона в винде. Так что аргумент - ну, так себе. Ну, и у Райдера есть студенческая лицензия, есть комьюнити эдишн, и есть еще, как минимум, один способ легально получить ключи для него от самого JB.